# How do 3rd Party Websites obtain in-game information /stats?

Tags: php, sql, database, statistics, game-center

So I just finished making a sample model of [Lol Name Checker](http://lolnamecheck.jj.ai/) within my local server. It checks the availability of a username for a game. Theres nothing mind blowing about it because all the information is available to the public on their website and even searching up their match history [officially here](http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#page/landing-page). In a smart manner, the site compiles his own database based on the content he crawls through from other sites (I assume but this seems the case). What puzzles me is how other websites can obtain in-game data that is not available online (so they cant use php to crawl their web pages for text content). For example in this [website](http://masteroverwatch.com/profile/pc/us/Adrian-13440). My question is how do they display data without having direct access to their sql database? Or is there an API I am missing for calling these functions that are available to developers (which I doubt)?

Comment: Riot Games has a API for _some_ data and it is fairly easy to re-implement the protocol to log in and fetch some data about users the same way you'd look it up in your client.

Comment: Oh alright. I thought so. Im trying to make one for a game like Tera. But since theres no public APIs Im guessing this would be impossible then?

Comment: YRiot Games has their API [here](https://developer.riotgames.com/) but for another game you should google for a library to log in or their api, but unfortunately, not a lot of games offer a API to access data this easily.